# Stripe, transfer from customer to our account

Tags: stripe-payments

Is it possible to transfer from the customer account to our own account?

Note: This is not a fee of transaction, but it's simply withdrawing from customer's account.

Here is a scenario: We introduce a user to the shopping center. Then the user pays in the shopping center (physically and not online payment). Then we get the invoices from the shopping center and at the end of the month, we should transfer some money from the shopping center. So, no online transaction, no fee. Just simply transferring money from the user's account to our account. (maybe there should be verification process from the shopping center, which is ok)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to decide how to model the relationship you have with the Shopping Center and the Shopper with Stripe, but one suggestion would be to consider the Shopping Center as your Customer, who then pays you based on referred Shoppers etc. This could be done many different ways, using [Invoices](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/overview), or [saved payment methods and off-session payments](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse#web-create-payment-intent-off-session), or with a [usage-based Subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/metered).

Alternatively, if you *were* facilitating payments from Shoppers to the Shopping Centers, you might use [Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/enable-payment-acceptance-guide) and set up the Shopping Centers as [Connected Accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/accounts) and the Shoppers as Customers. You would [collect application fees](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges#collecting-fees) for the payments you facilitate online. For offline payments, you could charge your connected accounts fees using [account debits](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-debits).

Comment: Thank you. I should read the docs to see whether they fit our needs or not.

Comment: There is a point about `invoices`. We want to automatically transfer from user's account to our own account. With `invoices`, user should pay the invoice through stripe payment.

Comment: Can you explain more about what you expect, or what doesn't fit your needs? You are effectively collecting payment for referrals from the shopping centers, right? Yes, the payments would be through Stripe if you're using Stripe services to conduct the payments.